# rails 3 wicked_pdf images from html into pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, wicked-pdf

I've encountered a problem with displaying images in pdf's and html's.

Basically what I want is to make my html view be downloadable  in pdf. So I've created a partial `_pdf_view.html.haml`, which looks (for now) like so:

```
%p
  = wicked_pdf_image_tag "vehicles/Toyota_Echo1-1.jpg"
```

then I simply render this partial both in `download.html.haml` and in `download.pdf.haml`. The idea is that the html file previews what is going to be downloaded as a pdf.

The funny part is that this code will put the image nicely in my pdf, but not in my html. In PDF there needs to be specified full file path, however, in html that won't fly. If I change the path to `"/vehicles/Toyota_Echo1-1.jpg"` then it is the other way around...

Any way around it, besides creating separate files or separate chunks of code just for images?

P.S I'm using: rails 3.2.12, wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9, wicked_pdf 0.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the image tag created based on the :format.

```
- if params[:format] == 'pdf'
  = wicked_pdf_image_tag 'vehicles/Toyota_Echo1-1.jpg'
- else
  = image_tag 'vehicles/Toyota_Echo1-1.jpg'
```

Comment: Hehehe, thanks. That worked like a charm. Kinda feel stupid, should have thought of the magic and power of `if..else` statement..